# Rotating an image on a mouse button click in pygame

Tags: pygame

I am trying to rotate this image constantly while the MOUSEBUTTONCLICK is activated, but when I run the MOUSEBUTTONCLICK nothing is happening. Here is the code that I have tried.

```
while True:
    'RotatingImg'
    image_surf = pygame.image.load('imagefile')
    image_surf = pygame.transform.scale(image_surf, (810,810))
    image_surfpos = image_surf.get_rect()
    screen.blit(image_surf, image_surfpos)
    degree = 0
    pygame.display.update()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        '''Quit Button'''
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 1:
            ## if mouse is pressed get position of cursor ##
            screen.blit(target1, target1pos)

            'RotatingImg'
            image_surf = pygame.image.load('C:\\Users\Leyton\Documents\Coding Stuff\Python\Apps\Fan_blades.png')
            image_surf = pygame.transform.scale(image_surf, (810,810))
            image_surfpos = image_surf.get_rect()
            screen.blit(image_surf, image_surfpos)
            degree = 0
            blittedRect = screen.blit(image_surf, image_surfpos)
            'Get center of surf for later'
            oldCenter = blittedRect.center
            'rotate surf by amount of degrees'
            rotatedSurf = pygame.transform.rotate(image_surf, degree)
            'Get the rect of the rotated surf and set its center to the old center'
            rotRect = rotatedSurf.get_rect()
            rotRect.center = oldCenter
            'Draw rotatedSurf with the corrected rect so it gets put in proper spot'
            screen.blit(rotatedSurf, rotRect)

            'Change the degree of rotation'
            degree += 5

            if degree > 0:
                degree = 0

            'Show the screen Surface'
            pygame.display.flip()
            'Wait 0 ms for loop to restart'
            pygame.time.wait(0)



        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP and event.button == 1:
            screen.blit(target, targetpos)
```

if **name** =='**main**':
    Game()

Answer (score 0):

1: Don't load images in the event loop. You'll want to keep an non-rotated version around, then rotate it on demand.

2: pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN only fires off when you first click the mouse button down. Holding the button down will not keep firing off the event.

3: You're resetting degree twice; first, you set it to 0, then you set it to 0 if it's greater than 0.

There's probably other issues as well.

Comment: What event could i use so the image will continue to spin instead of mousebuttondown

Comment: No such event. You either need to have some kind of "is_pressed" variable that gets set/unset on mouse down/up, or call pygame.mouse.get_pressed() every frame.